# Iterate over tuple list and dictionary to make calc

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

New to Python - is there a straightforward way to iterate over a tuple list and make a calculation using a performance threshold (i.e., daily sales % over/under budgeted sales)? Please see the info below:

```
daily_sales = [('A',150000),('B',73000),('C',110000),('D',231000),('E',66000)] 
budgeted_sales = {'A':140000,'B':103000,'C':80000,'D':20000,'E':90000}
performance_threshold = .20
```

Comment: Can you please post an example for a calculation you want to have between the three?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - to simplify my question, is there an easy way to just compare each list item against it's same dictionary item (e.g., if $150,000 > $140,000, then print "Over" else "Under"). If I can figure out that I can incorporate the threshold piece...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new to Python here is an easy way to do that without too complex syntax:

```
# For each tuple inside daily_sales
for sale in daily_sales:
  # Use the first element of that tuple as a key and check if it's inside the dictionary budgeted_sales
  if sale[0] in budgeted_sales:
    # Compare the value stored for that key with the second element of the tuple (which contains the other price) and print stuff
    if budgeted_sales[sale[0]] > sale[1]: print('Over')
    else: print('Under')
```

The check above is optional however it ensures that you don't bluntly access the dictionary with a key that doesn't exists and then try to add a non-existent value with an existent one.

Comment: @hegemony Btw if you want to do some calculations and store the results for later you can easily add an empty list before the loop, do your thing with the values from all three sources and then append the result to that list.

Answer (score 1):

To keep things simple, you can do this in a loop.  The first line loops through each tuple pair in `daily_sales`.  For the first pair, `item[1]` is 150000.  It then gets `item[0]` (i.e. A) from the dictionary.  Note that this will fail if there is no matching item in the dictionary.

```
for item in daily_sales:
    performance = item[1] / float(budgeted_sales.get(item[0])) - 1
    if performance > 0:
        print "Over {0:.2%}".format(performance)
    else:
        print "Under {0:.2%}".format(performance)

Over 7.14%
Under -29.13%
Over 37.50%
Over 1055.00%
Under -26.67%
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is something like this:

```
for i in daily_sales:
    if i[1] > budgeted_sales['A']:
    //Do something
```

The important bit here is that tuples are immutable, so you access it by referencing a position (e.g. i[0]). Dict entries can be accessed by referencing their key (e.g. myDict['myKey']

I Hope this helps!

Comment: Being immutable means that it cannot be changed; it does not mean that it has integer indexes.  You are correct about the integer indexes, but you have the incorrect reason.

Answer (score 0):

Just because no one mentioned it, you can unpack in the for loop to make the code simpler to understand (including the `performance_threshold`):

```
for day, sales in daily_sales:
    performance =  float(sales) / budgeted_sales[day]
    if performance > 1+performance_threshold:
        print "Over {0:.2%}".format(performance)
    elif performance < 1-performance_threshold:
        print "Under {0:.2%}".format(performance)
    else:
        print "Target {0:.2%}".format(performance)
```

Output:

```
Target 107.14%
Under 70.87%
Over 137.50%
Over 1155.00%
Under 73.33%
```